# Two Questions: How do I move faster in Blender & My Object Keeps Moving Away

Tags: 3d-view

So I'm trying to set a camera point in a picture render and I'm doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> so I can move to the right spot I want to and it's too slow.

Another thing is sometimes one of my parts get moved away when I do that. It really ticks me off. Any help?

Comment: Maybe there should be Shift+F ? It's where speed can be changed with mouse wheel for Fly mode, while Ctrl+F in Object mode doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

1st: Speed Increasing / Decreasing with mouse wheel

2nd: Increase Camera Clipping --> <kbd>N</kbd> in 3D View --> View --> Clip --> `End` --> *Increase Number here*